# Is it possible to update Vuze 4.3 to 4.7?

Tags: updates, software-center, vuze

I have been wondering how to update Vuze 4.3 I noticed it in the Ubuntu software that it only has 4.3 and been researching on how to get the latest installments.. if you could help on a step by step if it is possible to update vuze to it's latest version, much would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get Vuze 4.7 do this:

1. Uninstall your current version of Vuze.
2. Get the most current version [Here](http://www.vuze.com/download/)
3. Extract the file
4. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your
   keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder
   where the file was extracted, probably `/Downloads/vuze`
5. Run the azureus executable, by typing `./azureus`

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu utopic-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azureus
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Although your answer is 100% correct, it doesn't explain well *why* a user should do this, so [edit] your answer and drop me a note @Fabby so I can come back and upvote.  Also, please read the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**